# Labeling under a bubble in a bubble chart in amcharts4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I was trying to figure out how to label a bubble underneath it in amcharts 4 in a bubble chart like this:

[image: bubble chart example]

But I'm not finding anything official about it.

If you push a LabelBullet onto the series, the labels are centered on the data point, then you can use dx/dy to adjust their position, but the problem is on a bubble chart the bubbles change size relative to a data point.

This is what I've come up with so far, but I was hoping somebody might have something more official:

```js
            const bulletLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
            bulletLabel.label.text = options.bubbleLabelText;
            bulletLabel.label.paddingTop = 20;
            bulletLabel.label.fontSize = 12;
            series.heatRules.push(
                {
                    target: bulletLabel,
                    min: options.minRadius || 5,
                    max: options.maxRadius || 60,
                    property: 'dy'
                }
            );
```

This also only works when labeling underneath the bubble and I can't think of a way to make it work above the bubble instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [an adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for the `LabelBullet`'s `dy`. When that comes in, check the bullet's `dataItem.bullets` to grab a reference to its `CircleBullet` (used for bubbles), check its radius, then use that for your `dy`. You can also provide logic if you want it to go above or under the `CircleBullet`, e.g. if a value is less than `10`, go above, otherwise go below.

```js
// Sample data
{
  "date": "2015-01-08",
  "ay": 8,
  "by": 12.3,
  "aValue": 5,
  "bValue": 13,
  bubbleLabelText: "test"
}

const bulletLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
bulletLabel.label.text = "{bubbleLabelText}";
bulletLabel.label.fontSize = 12;
bulletLabel.adapter.add('dy', (dy, bullet) => {
  let radiusDy = dy;
  bullet.dataItem.bullets.iterator()(firstBullet => {
    const circleBullet = firstBullet[1];
    if (bullet.dataItem.dataContext.bubbleLabelText) {
      radiusDy = circleBullet.circle.radius;
      if(bullet.dataItem.values.valueY.value >= 10) {
        radiusDy += 12;
      } else {
        radiusDy = -1 * radiusDy - 12;
      }
    }
  })
  return radiusDy;
});
```

[Here's a fork](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a86361c54a4c369e8c49bdd931f8d0f5) of our [Bubble XY chart with date-based axis demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/xy-chart-date-based-axis/) with the above code:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a86361c54a4c369e8c49bdd931f8d0f5

You could try doing something similar with having a `Label` inside the `CircleBullet` (as a child of it), tinker with its `valign` and/or the `CircleBullet`'s `contentValign`, but you'd still have to dynamically adjust their `dy` so they go a bit above/below the circle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply! I never would have thought of this solution, I think I have to get used to the idea of adapters more.

Comment: @ShaneTheKing You're welcome! Yep, adapters, `ListTemplate`s, plenty of new, powerful introductions in v4. There are plenty of times there's multiple ways of doing things. Heat rules for example are basically a convenience tool for adapters!